# The "four hits" fault

Tags: rules, officiating, volleyball

Let me describe a specific situation:

**Team A serves the ball. Team B executes three hits to return it - they pass the ball, set it and then attack. After the attack, the ball touches both the top band of the net and the hands of the blocker (at the same time) and remains on the same part of the court.**

My question is: In such a situation, **is team B now entitled to another three hits**?

To me it seems they should be, for an oponent player was in contact with the ball.

Some other people around believe the oposite, specifically because of the contact of the ball with the top band of the net after the attack.

I have searched the current FIVB rules but did not find anything that would approve that claim. Is there such a rule in place?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, if you attack the ball, and the blocker makes any contact with the ball, and it comes back to your side, then your hits are reset (otherwise a block to your side would be a guaranteed point for them every time) and you can once again take up to three hits to put the ball over the net.

You'll notice that while *your* team is attacking, back row players are taught to cover behind, and to the side of your hitters - this is so that in this case -- where the block returns the ball -- they are able to dig it up and once again start another attack.

See: [FIVB Rule 14.4.1](http://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/documents/FIVB-Volleyball_Rules2013-EN_V08_20130516.pdf)

> "A block contact is not counted as a team hit. Consequently, after a 
>   block contact, a team is entitled to three hits to return the ball."

Thus, after a block, the blocking team, *or* the attacking team, are entitled to three team hits to return the ball.

Comment: So, just to make sure, the fact that the ball touched the net in adition to the block does not matter in any case (regardless of the proportions of the ball touching the net vs. the hands)?

Comment: Right, the touching of the net has no impact here - either way it's a block by the opponent in the front row, and resets the allowed hits for the team.

Comment: While reading through the rules, I have noticed that also rule no. 14.1.3 - "A block is completed whenever the ball is touched by a blocker." and the corresponding diagram no. 7 support your answer.